# Creating a multi-screen application using Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, screens

I'm using Qt Designer to create UI designs which I'm then converting into python code. Since I'm quite new to Qt I'd like to ask: is there a way I could implement a multi-screen application? I.e. having a next button clicked and getting a new set of options/widgets etc within the same window.

To be honest, I was developing using Kivy, and as slick as that is (especially with multiple screens) it depends on PyGame, which proves to be an enormous portability headache, so I had to switch to something else, and PyQt was the next feasible option (or so it seems).

Answer (score 2):

It's called a QWizard. It is not called a multi screen application, but if you search for wizard instead, you find lots of information.

### Links

- [Example with C++ code](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-trivialwizard.html)
- [PyQt QWizard documentation] http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwizard.html